# Is Avant Window Navigator Available For Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apt, ppa, 14.04, awn

I want to install avant-window-navigator on Ubuntu 14.04. I tried to install by following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:awn-testing/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator
```

But `sudo apt-get update` getting Error:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/awn-testing/ppa/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
```

and `sudo apt-get install avant-window-navigator` getting error:

```
E: Unable to locate package avant-window-navigator
```

So, Is AWN Available for 14.04 on any New PPA? Or **Should I Avoid Installing avant-window-navigator?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check launchpad you will see that [AWN Testing](https://launchpad.net/~awn-testing/+archive/ppa) has support for 13.10, 13.04 and 12.04. So no 14.04.

You have 2 options:

- wait for them to update to 14.04.
- install the 13.10 or 12.04 versions of AWN. You can do this by opening "software&updates" and editing the source list for AWN. If you change the distribution name you can install it from the older repositories. Mind you: it is possible. If it is wise I'll let you decide (mixing distributions can make a mess of your system).

Answer (score 0):

It means `avant-window-navigator` for ubuntu 14.04 LTS trusty has not been released on this ppa. Just wait for few days and I am sure trusty branch will be up and running for `avant-window-navigator` in `ppa:awn-testing/ppa`.

Comment: How you are sure?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can installing it using it's .deb http://pkgs.org/debian-squeeze/debian-main-i386/avant-window-navigator_0.4.0-2_i386.deb.html

Comment: Why the downvote? (I'm not saying it's wrongly downvoted, I just want to know _why_ it's wrong)